# Translating for-loop to block-loop? Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to translate these  2 for-loops to a loop with a block, but I keep on getting a Type error.

This is the original code: 
EDIT I have added what h1 and h2 are

```
h1 = gethashfromfile('arrtime.txt')
h2 = gethashfromfile('deptime.txt')
k1 = h1.keys
k2 = h2.keys
kcommon = k1 & k2
k_not_in_both = (k1 - kcommon) | (k2 - kcommon)

arr = kcommon.to_a

for i in 0...arr.size
 stay = h2[arr[i]] - h1[arr[i]]
 if stay < 0
   puts arr[i] + ': data issue'
 else
   puts arr[i] + ': stay ' + stay.to_s + ' minutes'
 end
end

arr2 = k_not_in_both.to_a
for i in 0...arr2.size
puts arr2[i] + ': data issue'
end
```

This is what I have so far:

```
arr.each do |i|
  stay = h2[arr[i]] - h1[arr[i]]
  if stay < 0
      puts arr[i] + ': data issue'
  else
      puts arr[i] + ': stay' + stay.to_s + ' minutes'
  end
end

arr2 = k_not_in_both.to_a
arr2.each { |x| puts arr2[x] + ': data issue'}
```

This is the error I am receiving:

```
 TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
    from (irb#1):202:in `[]'
    from (irb#1):202:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb#1):201:in `each'
    from (irb#1):201
```

Comment: You have not defined what `h1` and `h2` are or really what the desired result is. While you may get help understanding loops, us understanding the actual problem you are facing will lead to more constructive idiomatic answers in general

Comment: Note that in ruby, `for` loops and `each` loops get interpreted in exactly the same way by the interpreter. Somehow that has led to the convention that we should only use `each` (`each` is the internal name for these loops in MRI). So your question isn't really about translating a `for` loop into an `each`, but how to rewrite it in more idiomatic ruby :-)

Comment: @niels not correct, `for` loops are different. They don't create a local scope, and that is why we prefer `each` loops in Ruby!

Comment: you are so right! Must have made that up...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
arr.each do |i|
  # do something with i
end
```

`i` isn't an index, it's the element itself!

You can replace `arr[i]` by just `i`.

To avoid making this mistake, you could use more descriptive variable names :

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c']
letters.each do |letter|
  puts letter
end
# =>
# a
# b
# c
```

`letters[letter]` would throw an error, because `letters` is an array and `array[]` expects an integer as index, not a string.

Comment: should we mention `each_with_index` here? probably not. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev then we definitely shouldn't mention `each_index` at all